# Elastic beanstalk permanent log storage

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, scalability, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using elastic java beanstalk server on aws with rds.I am writing custom logs with my application in a custom directory in tomcat7 (path=/usr/share/tomcat7/).But on increasing load number of instances goes to more than 1 and after some time 1st instance got terminated and was replaced by another instance.So the custom logs are not created in those instances as custom directories are not created there.
            And also I want to store all custom logs and logs created by tomcat7 permanently.What should i do.

Answer (score 1):

EBS is the way to have persistent storage on an EC2 instance. So you can attach an EBS volume. And write the logs there (using a logging framework like logback)

To extend on that, you should rotate logs and look at a log-gathering solution like logstash/graylog/splunk/...

Comment: Is it that ebs can connect to one instance at a time?

Comment: Yes, but at least you don't lose the data. The log-aggregation though is a better option

Comment: Can you elaborate more as i am new to all this.I am using log4j for logging purpose.How will i configure so that when number of ec2 instances increases on increasing load they all store logs at one place and remain stored until i don't delete them.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your environment to automatically rotate logs to S3. Log publication to be S3 can be enabled following the guide given [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html).

See the section "Configuring Your Environment to Publish Logs to Amazon S3".

If you do not wish to use the web console, you can also use the following ebextension:

```
option_settings:
   - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:hostmanager
     option_name: LogPublicationControl
     value: true
```

Just create a file with these contents in a file called '.ebextensions/01-logs.config' in your app source and deploy it. Remember to turn on log publication to S3 you need to have an IamInstanceProfile configured for your environment. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.roles.logs.html) is some more information about this aspect.